# Console Crash At the end(Loop) Not Out of Bound Error

Tags: c++, data-structures

Hi i was creating a simple Vector Class for my studies. 
Just to store Variable **LONG**
i kept everything simple. When i build nothing was return error/ warning. 
Then after run the program, it works but the program crash.

Code Vector.h

```
class Vector{
public:
    Vector();
    void add(long i);
    void getData();
private:
    long *anArray;
    long maxSize;
    long position;
    void reSize(int i);
```

};

Vector.cpp

```
    Vector::Vector(){
    maxSize = 2;
    anArray = new long[maxSize];
    position = 0;
}

void Vector::add(long i){
    if(position==maxSize-1)
        reSize(maxSize * 2);

    anArray[position] = i;
    position++;
}

void Vector::reSize(int i){
    long *temp = new long[maxSize];
    for(int i =0; i<maxSize; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = anArray[i];
    }
    delete[] anArray;
    anArray = temp;
}

void Vector::getData(){

    for(int i = 0; i<position; i++)
    {
        cout << "Element" << i+1 << " : " << anArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Main

```
    int main()
{
    Vector vecStore;



    for(int i = 0; i <  1000; i++)
    {
        long a;
        vecStore.add(a = i + 1);
    }

     cout << "GET DATA _________ :: " << endl;
    vecStore.getData();
    return 0;
}
```

The program wouldn't crash if the input data small(e.g. 10-20)
but when i change it to 100 or even bigger. the program sometime crash and sometime its not.

Did i make a mistake?

Comment: `reSize` is broken. `for(int i =0; i<maxSize; i++)` shadows parameter `i`. Doesn't look like you ever increase `maxsize`

Comment: I dont quite get it, mind to expand you answer a bit??

Comment: You pass `i` as parameter, but then you declare a new `i` in the loop. **void Vector::reSize(`int i`){ ... for(`int i =0`; i<maxSize; i++)**

Comment: @FernandoCiam try to run it on a debugger and see how those variables change they values

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior. Possibly in more locations.

Comment: Can't you just search for it? We can't explain UB on every thread people post about it, or we'd never get anything useful done.

Comment: @FernandoCiam Updated answer and added a link to a definition of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
void Vector::add(long i){
    if(position==maxSize-1)
        reSize(maxSize * 2);

    anArray[position] = i;
    position++;
}
```

when `position==maxSize-1`, reSize is called to double the size of the array. Unfortunately, `reSize` is broken.

```
void Vector::reSize(int i){
    long *temp = new long[maxSize];
    for(int i =0; i<maxSize; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = anArray[i];
    }
    delete[] anArray;
    anArray = temp;
}
```

The parameter `i` is never used. This should be the new size of the `Vector`, but instead the new array is allocated with the same `maxSize` as the previous array. `maxSize` goes unchanged.

Back in `add`, data is stored at `position` and `position` is increased by one. This means on the next `add` `position` is equal to `maxSize`, so the check to prevent overrunning the array,

```
if(position==maxSize-1)
```

will not do what you want and the program writes outside the bounds of the array. From there, `position` keeps getting larger, will never be equal to `maxSize` minus one, and writes even further out of bounds, not that it matters at that point. [Undefined Behaviour has already been invoked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and Crom only knows what will happen. Maybe the program crashes, maybe the program crashes later, maybe it does something bizarre, and maybe it even chugs on looking like everything is working just fine.

You want something more along the lines of

```
void Vector::reSize(int newSize){ // note more descriptive name
    long *temp = new long[newSize]; // using new size, not old size
    for(int i =0; i<maxSize; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = anArray[i];
    }
    delete[] anArray;
    anArray = temp;
    maxSize = newSize; // store new size.
}
```

`Vector` also needs a destructor to clean up `anArray`, but in order to properly fix this error, here's a bit of recommended reading: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Well explained. Isn't accessing deleted pointer also UB? Not that code reaches that point anyway.

Comment: @Ron Would be. Not seeing that happen though.

Comment: Thank you so much, i’ll look further on the UB later. I didnt notice the shadow parameter because the name of variable obviously a mistake.